# [NSManagedObjectContext delete:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, core-data

core data getting on my nerves. i' m deleting old data and want to insert new data received from server.

now the deleting part gives a "sigabort":

> -[NSManagedObjectContext delete:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x522f550
>   2013-09-27 14:05:56.592 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSManagedObjectContext delete:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x522f550'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x320f82a3 0x39d4797f 0x320fbe07 0x320fa531 0x32051f68 0x1b6c53 0x1868e5 0x3a15f11f 0x3a16d259 0x3a16d3b9 0x3a193a11 0x3a1938a4)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

deleting happens in background and nsmanagedobjectcontext is a privet concurrency type
i printed the pointer for context and object context

> po context NSManagedObjectContext: 0x522f550

and

> po tmpCon.managedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext: 0x522f550>

and the code for deleting is:

```
     NSError *errorAllCons = nil;
    NSFetchRequest *allevents = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [allevents setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"TEventContact" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
    NSArray *allCons = [context executeFetchRequest:allevents error:&errorAllCons];
    for (TEventContact *tmpCon in allCons)
    {
        [context delete:tmpCon];
    }
```

and it crashes on `[context delete:tmpCon];`
can someone let me know what am i doing wrong?

Comment: `NSManagedObjectContext` does not have a `delete:` method, maybe [`deleteObject:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/deleteObject:)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use

```
 [context deleteObject:tmpCon];
```

It will solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

do it like this for deleting an object permanently

```
for (TEventContact *tmpCon in allCons)
{
    [context deleteObject:tmpCon] /// for deleting object in context
}    
[context save]; /// to reflect changes in database you need to save that context
```

without saving the context it doesn't reflect on data base and that may cause DIRTY_READ for another context